# Why is the bottom of the figure cut off?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am trying to update a figure created with the [jsphylosvg library](http://www.jsphylosvg.com/) which is based on [raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/). Someone [tried to clear and reload a tree](http://jsphylosvg.uservoice.com/forums/55902-general/suggestions/7252947-clear-and-reload-tree) and someone else [asked about multiple svg](http://jsphylosvg.uservoice.com/forums/55902-general/suggestions/5022268-show-multiple-svg-on-the-same-page-can-we-do-tha) on the jsphylosvg forum but they didn't get any answer. I took it a step further and managed to reload a tree by clearing the HTML content of the div and re-instantiating a tree. However the figure still gets cut off when another tree is instantiated -- even without clearing:

[image: Bottom cut off]

[Try it on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZVENG)
Edit:

**Any idea why this is happening?**

Thank you!

---

### About the MVCE

The [CodePen Playground](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbRWQV?editors=101) above (code below) is the best [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I could provide. It consists of two made up trees: a *coffee tree* and a *tea tree*. The finale goal is to have only the *tea tree* displayed (the *coffee tree* should be cleared out right away). However for now I can't even display those two trees side-by-side properly: the tea tree is cut off at the bottom (as seen in figure above). My main point here is to try to understand **why this cutting off is happening and how to fix it**.

---

### Some code

In case the link breaks.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="svgCanvas"></div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function() {
  var coffee = {
    newick: '(((Espresso:2,(Milk Foam:2,Espresso Macchiato:5,((Steamed Milk:2,Cappuccino:2,(Whipped Cream:1,Chocolate Syrup:1,Cafe Mocha:3):5):5,Flat White:2):5):5):1,Coffee arabica:0.1,(Columbian:1.5,((Medium Roast:1,Viennese Roast:3,American Roast:5,Instant Coffee:9):2,Heavy Roast:0.1,French Roast:0.2,European Roast:1):5,Brazilian:0.1):1):1,Americano:10,Water:1);'
  };

  var tea = {
    newick: '(((White:2,(Green:2,Oloong:5,((Black:2,Herbal:2,(Rooibos :1,Mate :1,Blooming :3):5):5,Blends:2):5):5):1, Fermented:0.1,(Chifir:1.5,((Iced:1,Lahpet:3,Thai:5,Yellow:9):2,Honey:0.1,British:0.2,Pu-erh:1):5,Peppermint:0.1):1):1,Chamomile:10,Ginger:1);'
  };

  coffee_canvas = new Smits.PhyloCanvas(
    coffee,
    'svgCanvas',
    500, 500);

  // Unsuccessful attempts at clearing the canvas

  /** #1 Clearing the HTML in div: cut off when re-instantiated **/
  // document.getElementById('svgCanvas').innerHTML = ""; 

  /** ##2 Clearing the content of div in jQuery: cut off when re-instantiated **/
  // $('#svgCanvas').empty();

  /** #3 Clearing the canvas: TypeError, svgCanvas is a div not a canvas **/
  // var ctx = document.getElementById('svgCanvas').getContext('2d');
  // ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500); // clear canvas

  tea_canvas = new Smits.PhyloCanvas(
    tea,
    'svgCanvas',
    500, 500);
};
```

**Librairies**

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/master/raphael.min.js`
`https://cdn.rawgit.com/guyleonard/jsPhyloSVG/master/jsphylosvg-min.js`

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the way you're clearing the canvas?

```
      var ctx = document.getElementById('svgCanvas').getContext('2d');
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500); // clear canvas
```

So, overall your code will look like this:

```
  window.onload = function() {
  var dataObject = {
    newick: '(((Espresso:2,(Milk Foam:2,Espresso Macchiato:5,((Steamed Milk:2,Cappuccino:2,(Whipped Cream:1,Chocolate Syrup:1,Cafe Mocha:3):5):5,Flat White:2):5):5):1,Coffee arabica:0.1,(Columbian:1.5,((Medium Roast:1,Viennese Roast:3,American Roast:5,Instant Coffee:9):2,Heavy Roast:0.1,French Roast:0.2,European Roast:1):5,Brazilian:0.1):1):1,Americano:10,Water:1);'
  };
  phylocanvas = new Smits.PhyloCanvas(dataObject, 'svgCanvas', 500, 500);

  // uncomment the line below to clear the canvas
  //document.getElementById('svgCanvas').innerHTML = ""; // Do not use this one

  var ctx = document.getElementById('svgCanvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500); // clear canvas

  phylocanvas = new Smits.PhyloCanvas(dataObject, 'svgCanvas', 500, 500);

};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this does not work, it throws a `TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getContext is not a function`. This is because the library inserts the canvas into a div tag (which does not have a getContext function). My code sample was probably ambiguous because the same tree was displayed twice and an error in the js made it look like the issue was solved. I have updated the [CodePen sandbox](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbRWQV?editors=101) to make it more obvious! I do believe that I should change the way I'm clearing the canvas though.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone, i had a very similar problem, on my page are 2 [jsphylo](http://www.jsphylosvg.com/) trees (one normal and one circular), i tried to clear and render the tree again, but this does not work with jsphylo, it's a library issue i think.

But what you can do, if you don't want to reload the entire page, is simply add 2 div's on your page and pre render the trees. Than use js to switch between them.

js:

```
        $("#switchView").click(function(){
            if ($("#svgCanvasCircular").is(":visible")){
                $("#svgCanvas").show();
                $("#svgCanvasCircular").hide();
            }else{
                $("#svgCanvas").hide();
                $("#svgCanvasCircular").show();
            }
        });
```

html:

```
<button id="switchView">show circular/rectangular tree</button>    
<div id="svgCanvas"> </div>
<div id="svgCanvasCircular" style="display:none;"> </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem myself, and since this issue doesn't seem to be solved anywhere online, I took the time to write a little band-aid script (using jQuery) to try and put the image back in the correct position.

I've posted it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9w4PXtLQ)

If you happen to have multiple SVGs on the page at once, you will need to change the jQuery to only access yours (e.g. if it's in a div with `id="tree"`, change `$('svg...)` to `$('#tree svg...)`.

This was my first time altering an SVG using Javascript, so I have to admit that I probably haven't done it in the most efficient way.